# How can I find out where the value of this field is set?

Tags: visual-workflow, integration

We've started using LeanData with our Salesforce installation. We installed LeanData from the Salesforce app store. One of the fields is:

```
LeanData__Campaign_Member_Object_Type__c
```

There is an alert there that says:

*"This Custom Field Definition is managed, meaning that you may only edit certain attributes."*

What I find odd is that I cannot find where the value in this field is being set.

If I click the button "Where is this used?" then I see all the reports where it is used, but I don't see where the value is being assigned. There is no Flow listed.

If I log into the LeanData admin, and look around, I still can't find the logic that sets this value.

If I list all of the Flows, then I see a Flow called "LeanData API FLow" but I'm not allowed to click into it. Unlike the Flows that I created, when I click on "LeanData API Flow" nothing happens. I am not shown the internals of that Flow.

How can I find the logic that sets this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not listed on the "where is this used?" page, then it means that it is used in a component you won't have access to, like on that flow. Flows that are part of managed packages are obfuscated/hidden just like Apex, unless they are templates (which is not the case for this one, apparently).

With this in mind, I would suggest contacting LeanData's documentation or reach to their support team for this.